# Issue: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.xx;

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I have an issue when i run jmeter distributed :

Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.200.22; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Master: 192.168.200.21
Slave: 192.168.200.22
i have configured remote-hosts in jmeter.properties and started jmeter-server.bat in the master machine and slave machine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M622v.png)

How do I fix it?

I try connect to the slave machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you need to open port 1099 (or whatever is the value of your `server_port` property) in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

Also be aware that the slave will need to send the test results back to the master so you need to open `client.rmi.localport` and up to 3 ports up in the master machine.

And finally for any JMeter configuration overrides you should use *user.properties* file

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, I have fixed the issue. I have opened the port in the system firewall and config localport in jmeter.properties. It worked